# Cancelling interval based on a promise result in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have this business logic where I want to check some data from a service every 1 second, and if that data returns some property to be true, I want to cancel the interval. For example:

```
  someFn() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getData, 1000, param1, param2);
  }

  private async getData(param1: string, param2: string) {
    const data = await this.service.getSomeData(param1);
    if (data && receipt.success) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!');
      console.log('Clearing interval', this.interval);
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }
```

However, the interval doesn't stop executing, even though I'm entering the if block and SUCCESS is printed out. The interval seems to be undefined. I'm guessing this is because of some promise magic but I can't quite grasp why. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The button calling `someFn` is this.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myService.someFn()">Do Logic</button>
```

Edit2: If I console.log(this.interval) inside the `someFn` function right below where I set it, it logs an id. But inside the getData, `this.interval` is undefined.

Comment: where is someFn called, if its called more than once you ll loose the previous id

Comment: someFn is called on a button click once, it does some logic and then sets the interval. The params passed to getData are good, however `this.interval` is undefined.

Comment: is it called with ()=> or fucntion on that button handler?, can you expose that eventListener here

Comment: @EugenSunic edited the question!

Comment: try (click)="myService.someFn.bind(this)" to inject the components object

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I've edited the question again

Comment: @EugenSunic I've solved it by executing getData into the callback of setInterval. It probably didn't bind this.interval value to the scope of the service since I was only passing a reference to the fn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Instead of passing a reference to the setInterval, I'm executing the function inside the callback. So:

```
 someFn() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getData, 1000, param1, param2);
  }
```

becomes

```
 someFn() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getData(param1, param2), 1000);
  }
```

and it works.

Comment: OK, but maybe not for the reason you think. `this.interval = setInterval(this.getData.bind(this), 1000, param1, param2);` should also work. The `bind(this)` is necessary to convey the meaning of `this` to the otherwise detached `this.getData()`.